# Mobilefirst Plugin Doesnt Support Android 9 for Security Login

Tags: authorization, ibm-mobilefirst, android-9.0-pie, mobilefirst-cli

cordova-plugin-mfp

When using in Andoird 9 throws error for WLAuthorizationManager.login.

```
03-01 09:05:21.852   660 25727 I netd    : ;; res_nquery(ukd-climf8.peluk.org, 1, 1)
03-01 09:05:22.527 25320 25454 D com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.ChallengeHandlerPlugin: ChallengeHandlerPlugin.execute in ChallengeHandlerPlugin.java:42 :: inside ChallengeHandlerPlugin execute for action createSecurityCheckChallengeHandler
03-01 09:05:22.528 25320 25538 W System.err: java.lang.Error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: The BC provider no longer provides an implementation for KeyPairGenerator.RSA.  Please see https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/cryptography-changes-in-android-p.html for more details.
03-01 09:05:22.529 25320 25538 W System.err:    at com.worklight.wlclient.auth.WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.invokeRegistrationRequest(WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.java:751)
03-01 09:05:22.529 25320 25538 W System.err:    at com.worklight.wlclient.auth.WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.invokeRegistrationRequest(WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.java:473)
03-01 09:05:22.529 28397 28397 I PhenotypeExpConfig: refreshConfiguration() : Force = false : UpdateAvailable = false : Age = 9 minutes : MaxAge = 720 minutes
03-01 09:05:22.529 25320 25538 W System.err:    at com.worklight.wlclient.auth.WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.loginWithRegistration(WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.java:1294)
03-01 09:05:22.529 25320 25538 W System.err:    at com.worklight.wlclient.auth.WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.login(WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.java:486)
03-01 09:05:22.530 28397 28397 I AndroidIME: PasswordIme.onDeactivate()
03-01 09:05:22.530 25320 25538 W System.err:    at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLAuthorizationManager.login(WLAuthorizationManager.java:125)
03-01 09:05:22.530 25320 25538 W System.err:    at com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.execute(WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.java:157)
03-01 09:05:22.530 25320 25538 W System.err:    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:98)
03-01 09:05:22.530 25320 25538 W System.err:    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:132)
03-01 09:05:22.530 25320 25538 W System.err:    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:57)
03-01 09:05:22.530 25320 25538 W System.err:    at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
03-01 09:05:22.530 25320 25538 W System.err:    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
03-01 09:05:22.531 25320 25538 W System.err:    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
03-01 09:05:22.531 25320 25538 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
03-01 09:05:22.531 25320 25538 W System.err:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
03-01 09:05:22.531 25320 25538 W System.err: Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: The BC provider no longer provides an implementation for KeyPairGenerator.RSA.  Please see https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/cryptography-changes-in-android-p.html for more details.
03-01 09:05:22.532 25320 25538 W System.err:    at sun.security.jca.Providers.checkBouncyCastleDeprecation(Providers.java:563)
03-01 09:05:22.532 25320 25538 W System.err:    at sun.security.jca.Providers.checkBouncyCastleDeprecation(Providers.java:330)
03-01 09:05:22.532 25320 25538 W System.err:    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyPairGenerator.java:303)
03-01 09:05:22.532 25320 25538 W System.err:    at com.worklight.common.security.WLCertManager.generateKeyPair(WLCertManager.java:108)
03-01 09:05:22.532 25320 25454 D com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.ChallengeHandlerPlugin: ChallengeHandlerPlugin.execute in ChallengeHandlerPlugin.java:49 :: inside ChallengeHandlerPlugin createSecurityCheckChallengeHandler
03-01 09:05:22.532 25320 25538 W System.err:    at com.worklight.common.security.WLOAuthCertManager.generateKeyPair(WLOAuthCertManager.java:80)
03-01 09:05:22.532 25320 25538 W System.err:    at com.worklight.wlclient.auth.WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.signRegistrationData(WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.java:758)
03-01 09:05:22.532 25320 25538 W System.err:    at com.worklight.wlclient.auth.WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.getRegistrationParams(WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.java:591)
03-01 09:05:22.532 25320 25538 W System.err:    at com.worklight.wlclient.auth.WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.invokeRegistrationRequest(WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.java:711)
03-01 09:05:22.533 25320 25538 W System.err:    ... 13 more
```

Comment: What is the version of cordova-plugin-mfp ? Can you update to the latest where this change has been accommodated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved right when Android 9 was released. 
Upgrade to the latest IBM MobileFirst client SDK to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thank you the latest works fine can you please as well update the plugin.xml to say it supports android 9 it still says till 8

Comment: Where did you see Android version in our plugin.xml? We do not mention Android OS level in plugin.xml

Comment: Plugin.xml now it got updated thank you .   <engine name="cordova-android" version="&gt;=6.1.2 &lt;9" />

Comment: That's cordova-android version. Do not confuse it with Android OS version